# accordion toggle collapsing more than targeted divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my current piece of code when i try to collapse a letter it collapses the first div of the content when it should collapse all the divs within a letter header - i am not sure how to alter my JavaScript to properly collapse divs within a div.

```
<div class="accordion-group" data-bind="foreach: Types">
    <div class="text_x-large header"> <span data-bind="text:Name()"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="testing" data-bind="foreach: Users">
        <!-- ko if: Letter -->
        <div class="text_x-large letterHeader list_accordion_toggle" data-bind="visible: $parent.ShowLetter(), text: Letter"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div class="type_list_item smoke_hover" data-bind="template: { name: 'list'}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_accordion_toggle', function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('type_list_item collapse').next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. I've created a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasrus/Jwesm/). Are you saying when you click on "A" you want Aardvarks and Bandicoots to hide?

Comment: @jasonscript your fiddle is how i would like for my code to work. except you have the content within A as list and for me each item is an individual div

Comment: @jasonscript also the fiddle has the list written out but for me the data is being looped from foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to adjust your markup to include a containing `DIV` element. Like so: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasrus/Jwesm/1/)

**EDIT:**

Knockout allows you to set your own markup, so you should be able to modify it like this:

```
<div class="accordion-group" data-bind="foreach: Types">
<div class="text_x-large header"> <span data-bind="text:Name()"></span> 
</div>
<div class="testing" data-bind="foreach: Users">
    <!-- ko if: Letter -->
    <div class="text_x-large letterHeader list_accordion_toggle" data-bind="visible: $parent.ShowLetter(), text: Letter"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="type_list_item smoke_hover" data-bind="template: { name: 'list'}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: my divs are being generated from the foreach loop and i think within that lays my problem

Comment: I added the wrapper div and changed my javascript to target wrapper but i am still only getting the first item with A to collapse and leaving the remaining content within A showing

Comment: your js can also be simplified now:`$(document).on('click', '.list_accordion_toggle', function (event) {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});`

Comment: could (this) be only targeting just one div? and not being applied to all the divs within A?

Comment: In this case `this` is referring to the object that initiated the `click` event, so it should only be the "A" div. `Next` gets the next element, in this case it should be the "wrapper" div, and then toggles it on or off

Comment: ya it's only collapsing the next div  and not all the divs within the wrapper div. could i use `.nextUntil()` and pass in when it hits the next header?

Comment: I haven't used `nextUntil` before but it seems to work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasrus/Jwesm/4/) but I'd be worried about what happens for the last letter element. This code moves `nextUntil` it finds an element with the class `letterHeader`

Comment: Great, glad we got there in the end